# Proof in Graph theory, trees

Tags: graph-theory

> Let $G$ be an acyclic graph with $c$ components. Show that the number of edges of $G$ is $n-c$.

I tried to write an indirect proof, but I'm not sure that this is the appropriate way to solve the problem. I think that I can to reverse the question to the definition, that: "A forest is an undirected graph, all of whose connected components are trees; in other words, the graph consists of a disjoint union of trees."

Comment: It suffices to show that the number of edges in a tree on $n$ vertices is $n-1$; the result for forests follows immediately from this.

Comment: ^That's the answer. Do you know how to prove that the number of edges of a tree with n vertices is n-1?

Comment: Yes, I can solve the rest, I'll send it soon.:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can prove the result prove by using introduction on $n$,the number of vertices.The answer is obviously true for $n=1,2,3$. Let be the answer true for all trees with fewer than $n$ vertices. Let $T$ be a tree with $n$ vertices and let be $e$ an edge with end vertices $u$ and $v$. So the only path between $u$ and $v$ is $e$. Therefore deletion of $e$ from $T$ disconnects $T$. Now $T-e$ consists of exactly two components $T_{1}$ and $T_{2}$ say, and as there were no cycles tp begin with, each component is a tree. Let $n_{1}<n$ and $n_{2}<n$. Thus by induction hypothesis, number of edges in $T_{1}$ and $T_{2}$ are respectively $n_{1}-1$ and $n_{2}-1$. Hence the number of edges in $T=n_{1}-1+n_{2}-1+1=n_{1}+n_{2}-1=n-1$